# Need assistance removing duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm looking to combine data from two tables but experiencing an issue with some duplicates. Table1 has basic user information like first and last name. Table2 has additional information like address, city and zip. The issue I'm running into is some users have multiple entries in Table2 because their address has been updated.

I tried a LEFT JOIN. It almost works but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the duplicate entries. I just need the latest address entry, which could be determined by the higher "AutoID" identifier (see image for an example of what I'm referencing).

Thoughts?

[Sample Tables for visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MPvc.png)

```
SELECT TOP (9000) [Table1].[ID]
      ,[Table1].[LastName]
      ,[Table1].[FirstName]
      ,[Table2].Address1
      ,[Table2].[City]
      ,[Table2].[State]
      ,[Table2].ZipCode
FROM *****.dbo.Table1
LEFT JOIN *****.dbo.Table2 ON (Table1.ID = Table2.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (9000) [Table1].[ID]
      ,[Table1].[LastName]
      ,[Table1].[FirstName]
      ,[Table2].Address1
      ,[Table2].[City]
      ,[Table2].[State]
      ,[Table2].ZipCode
FROM *****.dbo.Table1
LEFT JOIN *****.dbo.Table2 ON (Table1.ID = Table2.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT TOP (9000) 
       t1.[ID]
      ,t1.[LastName]
      ,t1.[FirstName]
      ,t2.Address1
      ,t2.[City]
      ,t2.[State]
      ,t2.ZipCode
FROM *****.dbo.Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY AutoID DESC) rn
    FROM *****.dbo.Table2 t2
) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND r2.rn = 1
```

The subquery ranks records having the same `ID` by descending `AutoID`. Then, the outer query filters on the top record per group.

Another option is a lateral join:

```
SELECT TOP (9000) 
       t1.[ID]
      ,t1.[LastName]
      ,t1.[FirstName]
      ,t2.Address1
      ,t2.[City]
      ,t2.[State]
      ,t2.ZipCode
FROM *****.dbo.Table1 t1
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP (1) t2.*
    FROM *****.dbo.Table2 t2
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
    ORDER BY t2.AutoID DESC
) t2
```

Side note: the outer query uses `TOP`, but the dataset is not sorted. Consider adding a proper `ORDER BY` clause to the query in order to make the resultset predictable and stable.

Comment: If I try the lateral join then I get "The multi-part identifier "t2.Address1" could not be bound"

Comment: @iTDeStruXion: that would be suprising - unless `Table2` has no column called `Address1` (in which case your original query would fail too).

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function to get the desired output -

```
SELECT TOP (9000) [Table1].[ID]
       ,[Table1].[LastName]
       ,[Table1].[FirstName]
      ,[Table2].Address1
      ,[Table2].[City]
      ,[Table2].[State]
      ,[Table2].ZipCode
FROM *****.dbo.Table1
LEFT JOIN (select t2.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by autoid desc) as seq_num from *****.dbo.Table2 t2 ) Tb2 ON (Table1.ID = Tb2.ID)
Where Tb2.seq_num = 1;
```